# How to increase the row number column width in jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

In my JQuery Grid, I have a parameter named **rownumbers**.

```
jQuery("#dateInfo").jqGrid({   
url : theURL,
datatype : "json",
sortable: false,
colNames:['Date & Time'],
colModel:[{name:'arrivalTime',index:'arrivalTime', sortable: false, align:'left', width:200, editable:true,editoptions:{size:30}}],
pager : '#dateInfojsonmap',
rownumbers: true,     
viewrecords: true
});
```

When I set the parameter **rownumbers** to true, I get the row numbers for each row in the grid table. How can I increase the width of the row number column? I tried to update the CSS style, but it hasn't worked.

Can anyone tell me how to increase the width of the row number column in the jqGrid?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can control the width of the show row numbers columns by settings the rownumWidth property (default is 25).

from http://www.trirand.com/blog/phpjqgrid/examples/appearance/rownumbers/default.php

Comment: @Vijay Indeed, it is the carrot that drives us back wanting more!